React Input component for currency number field to display from 0.01, 0.12, 1.23, 12.34 and so on
I want to create an input React component for a monetary amount and I would like the placeholder to be 0.00 but upon typing, the value should be updated digit by digit without the need to type a .. So, for example, an amount of 1,234.56 should show as:
0.01
0.12
1.23
12.34
123.45
1,234.56

And when erasing a number then the revert order:
1,234.56
123.45
12.34
1.23
0.12
0.01

But, unfortunately, I can't get any of it to work. I tried an onChange event and onKeyDown event too with no success.
I am using a ShadCN component if that matters

Please show us your attempts.

If you want to use a library for this, you can look at : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-currency-input-field

That doesn't work well for decimal numbers because I still have to type in "." and it adds numbers from left to right instead of right to left

I posted an answer, I think you'll have to handle a few more cases than just the exemple.

You could format the currency with a number formatter, and parse it with parseInt.
You will need to format on input, and validate on keydown.


const currencyFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2
});

initCurrencyFields();
document.forms['receipt'].addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);

function onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const values = [...e.target.elements]
    .filter(el => el.classList.contains('currency-input'))
    .map(el => el.value || '?');
  console.log(...values);
}

function initCurrencyFields(selector = '.currency-input') {
  document.querySelectorAll(selector)
    .forEach(el => {
      el.placeholder = '$0.00';
      el.addEventListener('input', formatCurrency);
      el.addEventListener('keydown', validateInput);
    });
}

function formatCurrency(e) {
  const inputField = e.target;
  const number = parseInt(inputField.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''), 10);

  inputField.value = !isNaN(number)
    ? currencyFormatter.format(number / 100)
    : ''; // Clear field if input is not a valid number
}

function validateInput(e) {
  // Allow only number keys, control keys, and decimal points
  if (!/[0-9]|Backspace|ArrowLeft|ArrowRight|Delete|Tab|Enter/.test(e.key)) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent non-numeric and non-control keys
  }
}
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 4.33rem !important; }

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 1rem;
}

form[name="receipt"] {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

form[name="receipt"] > button[type="submit"] {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
<form name="receipt">
  <label for="item-a">Item A:</label>
  <input class="currency-input" id="item-a" name="a" type="text">
  <label for="item-b">Item B:</label>
  <input class="currency-input" id="item-b" name="b" type="text">
  <label for="item-c">Item C:</label>
  <input class="currency-input" id="item-c" name="c" type="text">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>




Thank you! This is the correct answer. I made the required changes to use it as a react component and it works exactly as I want! StackOverflow 1 x 0 ChatGPT

You can listen to a change event, get the value from the input field and then format it as you want :


const inputField = document.getElementById('inputCurrency');
inputField.addEventListener("input", function() {
  inputField.value = formatValue(inputField.value)
})

// Exemple : Format every 3 numbers
function formatValue(value) {
  const splittedValue = value.match(/\d{1,3}/g) // Split the entered value (ex : 130000) in groups of 3 numbers
  return splittedValue.join(",") // Sends back the result like this : 130,000 

}
<input type="text" id="inputCurrency" />




I formatted your example into a snippet you can run here on the site. It doesn't seem to exactly do the trick.

Fixed with a little regex

Yet this doesn't do what OP wants – they want to be able to type in one zero zero zero and end up with 10,00, or type in two five zero five zero and end up with "250,50", etc.

I didn't meant my answer to be a complete one, rather a lead on how to listen to the change event and then give one example on how to format the value.
